# They both jumped up when they saw Megan carry in the cage

Tags: usage

In this scenario, why was ***carry in*** used instead of past tense ***carried in*** or third person singular ***carries in***?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use a verb like see, hear, feel, etc, about actions, we can use the base or infinitive form of the verb without 'to' (the zero infinitive). With verbs of perception, the pattern is verb + object + zero infinitive.

> I saw Megan **carry** in the cage.
>
> He heard his father **shout** at the dog.
>
> I felt the needle **pierce** my skin.
>
> She felt the spider **crawl** up her leg.

[English grammar (infinitive)](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/)